# print_r works at times?

Tags: php

I obtain data from the model in an array format, I would like to know why I can't print_r the result without using exit() function right after it ?

this works:

```
    function someview()
{
    $result=$this->User->getdatafrommodel();
            print_r($result);
            exit();
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'usernotexist'));
    }
}

function usernotexist()
{
    $this->loadSkin();
}
```

this prints an empty Array.

```
    function someview()
{
    $result=$this->User->getdatafrommodel();
            print_r($result);
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'usernotexist'));
    }
}

function usernotexist()
{
    $this->loadSkin();
}
```

Could someone tell me why so it is ?

Comment: What errors do you get, if any?

Comment: Are you using any kind of output buffering?

Comment: Does it redirect inside the `if(!empty($result))`?

Answer (score 1):

In the second block of code, as results is empty this line is called in the else block:

```
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'usernotexist'));
```

So your output would appear to be a different page without the exit() statement.